# Spatial auto-correlation function of $\sin^2(2\theta)$ in terms of that of $\theta$

Tags: autocorrelation, random-field

Let $\theta$ be an isotropic random field which has a unifrom pdf $U[0,2\pi]$ and whose auto-correlation function is $R_{\theta \theta}(|y-x|) = \mathbb{E}[\theta(x)\theta(y)]$ wherein x and y are space variables. Is there a way to relate the auto-correlation function of the random field $\sin^2(2\theta)$ to $R_{\theta \theta}$?

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to see how all these assumptions are consistent.  For instance, the expression for autocorrelation implies $E[\theta(x)]=0$ for all $x,$ which isn't possible for a density supported on $[0,2\pi].$ Could you exhibit an example of the kind of field you're describing?

Comment: Thanks a lot @whuber for your reply. Indeed, I did not understand how you deduced from the expression of the autocorrelation function that the average of $\theta$ is 0 at any point. To precise more the problem, I have a random rotation at any given point in a 2d space following the stated uniform pdf and then I obtain a quantity of interest as a function of $\theta$ (which is $\sin(2\theta)^2$ and I need to calculate the autocorrelation of this random field in terms of that of $\theta$.

Comment: The autocorrelation is defined in terms of *standardized* values rather than the values themselves; in particular, your formula implicitly assumes they all have zero means.  But the more fundamental problem is that the formula makes no sense at all because $\theta$ is not defined! It is defined only up to an integral multiple of $2\pi.$  This makes an expectation meaningless.  You likely need to use techniques of [tag:circular-statistics].  It would help for you to describe the situation you actually have rather than giving us this abstract (and probably misleading) account.

Comment: @whuber: actually the fact that $\theta$ is not a zero-mean random field will only add a constant ($-\pi^2$) to the auto-correlation function that I've written in my question. That being said, this constant has nothing to do with the solution of the problem itself. thanks again for your comment.

Comment: Just to be clear: in your situation that constant isn't even defined.  The problem is that the field is a stochastic process defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with values in the circle $S^1.$ Your $U$ is merely a *discontinuous parameterization* of $S^1.$ One simple trick is to replace it by the well-defined coordinates $\cos(U)$ and $\sin(U),$ but that's only one of many possible approaches.  The choice of analysis ought to depend on what you are studying, how you are measuring it, what you assume about it, and what your objectives are.  That information would help people answer your question.